# How to make working JS project works in Angular?

Tags: angular, youtube, youtube-api

I created an interactive videos project with HTML + CSS + JS working with YouTube API.
I would like to implement it in an Angular component but I'm unable to succeed.

**My working project**
This is the tree of the project :

```
/Project
|
+-- index.html
|    
+-- /css
|  |  
|  +-- customTheme.css
|  +-- videojs.markers.min.css
|  +-- interaction.css
|    
+-- /js
|  |  
|  +-- videojs-markers.min.js
|  +-- interaction.js
|
+-- /media
|  |  
|  +-- some medias .png
|
```

The idea is to recreate the index.html, interaction.css and interaction.js files in an Angular component, and to import the others files.

**My Angular Component**
It is composed of 3 files: component.html, component.css, and component.ts. The component.ts file is :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I spent hours trying to recreate this project. I succeeded in displaying the YouTube video with YouTube API and to display some stuff on screen (pure CSS). But my **working project** goes further: the video is paused automatically, and Modals appears on screen to create interactivity with users. I've got lots of errors in the Console with Angular and I think this is because my implementation of the project in Angular is bad.
So, **the main questions** are: where and how should I copy my code to recreate my working project in an Angular Component? How could I import css / js files in an Angular Component to make them work together? Thanks!

Comment: Your project it's only in one page? If not, CSS and JS loads for every page or only index?

Comment: First how advanced are you with angular did you go through its documentation? Second, do you really need angular it usually adds some unnecessary abstraction and if you have vanilla js solution it's probably more efficient?

Comment: @GabrielLopes My project is only one page of HTML, one page of CSS and one page of JS + additionnal CSS and JS libraires, all loaded in my HTML.

Comment: @Xesenix A created a complete web app with Angular and now I would like to add a new functionnality, this is why I use Angular.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your css files in src folder, with default styles.css
2. on Angular.json file, import all the css files.

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "src/customTheme.css",
  "src/videojs.markers.min.css",
  "src/interaction.css"
],
```

3. Copy Headers from your index.html and paste on index.html of angular app (inside Src folder)
4. Copy the code inside body tag of your html, paste on home.component.html
5. Here you have 2 options, create a folder "assets" and paste here or paste .js files and .png files on src folder.
6. If you create Assets folder, on angular.json, you have a "assets" array, put your new assets folder.

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
```

Last, redirect your files link to new location. VSCode will help with this.